# Forgotten password page help [PHP/HTML]

Tags: php, html

I have a CMS, I am creating a forgotten password page, the page will require a user to enter an email address and the code will find it in the database and send them an email, in my database, i have multiple users accounts assigned to one email address.
I want it so that if the user enters an email address and it was more than one account assigned to it, to error a message saying please contact your admin, but atm, it is not doing this. Any suggestions?

Here is my forgotten password page code:

```
                    if ($lookup) {
                        $user->sendPasswordResetEmail();
                        echo"sent email";
                        } elseif ($lookup) {
                            echo "please contact your admin";
                                }else{ 
                                $echo"Can't find user";
                                }
            }
    }else{
        echo "please enter an email address";
        }
}
```

I take the information from a different file, here is the snippet for the code where I take the database:

```
 $resetsystem = $db->query($qry);
 if ($resetsystem && $resetsystem->num_rows == 1) {
 $that->setUserData($rs->fetch_assoc());
 return true;
        }
            if ($resetsystem && $resetsystem->num_rows > 1) {
                return;
            }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: In the first code block, this seems funky: `$numfound = $`

Comment: Your `elseif` is not checking for null, it's checking for true.

Comment: sorry i forgot to remove the $numfound = $

Comment: @JeremiahWinsley thanks for the reply, i don't want it to check for null, i want the elseif to check if there is more than one email address and then output the error message

Comment: Your function returns `null` when there's more than one email address. To check that, you'd check for `null`. If you don't want that, change your function to return something different.

Comment: Is there a way to have value from if ($rs && $rs->num_rows > 1) returned to the forgotten password page? the idea is if the is moer than one row in the database with that email address to then return that value so I can error it out. My english is not so great sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update following code:

```html
function lookupByEmail($userID) { 
  global $db; 
  $this->id = $userID; $qry = " SELECT user_id, user_first_name, user_last_name, user_username, user_email, user_suspended FROM cms_users WHERE user_email = " . $db->SQLString($this->id) . " AND user_deleted
= 0;"; 
$rs = $db->query($qry); 
if ($rs && $rs->num_rows == 1) { 
  $this->setUserData($rs->fetch_assoc()); 
  return 1; 
} 
if ($rs && $rs->num_rows > 1) { 
  return 2; 
} 
return 0; 
}
```

and then where you are checking the $found variable do these updates

```html
if ((int)$found == 1) {
  $user->sendPasswordResetEmail();
  $str_Message = '<div class="success_message">User found, an email has been dispatched to you.</div>';
} elseif ((int)$found > 1) {
  $errors->defineError("too_many_users", "please contact your admin", array());
}else{ 
  $errors->defineError("user_not_found", "The specified user could not be found.  Please try again.", array());
}
```

Comment: Ah this worked, can you please explain these changes? I am still learning, if you could explain in detail I would appreciate it.

Comment: In lookupByEmail i have changed the return values from boolean to int so we can cater more than one case e.g. 0,1 and 2 and in in $found if condition i have use these return values, if my answer work for you put it as answered so other with same issue can be helped.

Comment: I have set it as answered, why have you set the cases to 0 1 and 2, is there any meaning to those numbers? can it not work with true and false?

Comment: True are false are just two values and we need 3 return values in our case, one for if true one if false and one if true but have more than one results that's why i have change it

Comment: i have changed my code and adjusted your answer too, please could you review the changes.